# Getting error null object reference when passing array in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to pass some number from an array in  so the TextView in my fragment activity changed into **212** based index that I put in:

`textView.setText(samplearray[1]);`

Then I'm getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference

I don't know why the array is not passed through,

This is my HomeFragment :

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    int[] samplearray = {22,212,333};

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtvhomefragment);
        textView.setText(samplearray[1]);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View ViewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return ViewRoot;
    }
}
```

how to fix the `null object reference` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get the TextView from your inflated layout, as such (I used text_view for the TextView ID from your `fragment_home` XML layout):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // Get the TextView
    textView = viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    // And now set the text
    textView.setText(samplearray[1]);

    return viewRoot;
}
```

Comment: also should change the  ```textView.setText(samplearray[1]);``` to ```textView.setText(String.valueOf(samplearray[1]));``` because its int , should be string to set text